# How can I get rid of module specific libraries repositories in application module?

Tags: android, gradle, module

I'm in the process of modularisation my single-module app but I'm stuck on one problem that I can't deal with.
I have 2 modules, let's call them :app (com.android.application module) and :library (com.android.library).

The :library module has a dependency on another android library (brightcove sdk for the player) and it's build.gradle looks like:

```
repositories {
   maven { url 'http://repo.brightcove.com/releases' }
}
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation "com.brightcove.player:exoplayer2:6.3.1"
}
```

My :app module just depends on :library module

```
dependencies {
   implementation (':library')
}
```

But the problem is that during sync IDE complains to me

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve com.brightcove.player:exoplayer2:6.3.1.
```

And it only gets resolved after adding the same repository to :app module.
But I don't really want either to duplicate repositories for all my aar dependencies from ':library' in ':app' either to store this 'repositories' in top-level build file.

What's the proper way to handle such situations in multi module android apps?

Comment: Just change `implementation` to `api` inside your library module. And this dependency will be propagated to `app` module.

Answer (score 1):

When your app wants to access a third party which is used in your library, you should add its dependency to your app build.gradle too. Because there is no relation like a chain between them and third party is only visible in your library. So, you should add this in app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
     implementation "com.brightcove.player:exoplayer2:6.3.1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually there's no need to add this dependency to :app module. It works ok even if I just include 
repositories {  maven { url 'http://repo.brightcove.com/releases' } }
w/o adding library in dependencies.
But it seems a bit strange to me.